# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file: csvreader

Tags: python, csv

Not sure why this is occurring, I have full admin privileges to the csv file as shown below:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\legos\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\firebase.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    i=0
    for row in reader:
        i+=1
    j = 0
    for row in reader:
        j+=1
        if (j == i):
            lasturl = str(row)
    print lasturl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the file (`for row in reader`) "consumes" the file, so you can't iterate through it again without taking some action.

Options include:

- Rewrite your code to not have to iterate the file twice
- Put the second loop inside a separate (and not nested) `with open() as f`
- "rewind" the underlying file pointer (using `f.seek(0)`) between the two iterations  (I'm not sure how well this would work, but worked for me using python 2.7.14 on a linux machine)

Comment: Like this? with `open('C:\\Users\\legos\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\firebase.csv', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     x=0
      for row in reader:
       x+=1
 with open('C:\\Users\\legos\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\firebase.csv', 'rt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

  j = 0
      for row in reader:
       j+=1
       if (j == x):
        lasturl = str(row)
     print lasturl` That doesn't work, throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the directory should not have any double slashes except for before firebase.csv